# Laravel Auth Logout() + Session Flush() not logging out user

Tags: php, session, laravel-4

I've been experiencing inability to successfully logout of my application for about 3 months.

The controller code on the logout route:

```
Auth::logout();
Session::flush();
```

For what it's worth, the remember token column is not null in the users table, and the session config drive is file.

EDIT:

I notice the remember token value is being changed in the DB after logout while exhibiting behavior of staying logged in.

Comment: in your logout form are you using delete method? to delete session

Comment: I'm having this problem whether I logout through form or Postman calling my PUT user/logout route.

Comment: the form method needs to be specific to the controller.  it needs to be DELETE.  Please post your view with logout button

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by form method. You mean HTTP VERB?

Answer (score 3):

try using

```
public function getLogout() {
    Auth::logout();
    // Session::flush();
    return Redirect::to('login')->with('message', 'Your are now logged out!');
}
```

To logout and redirect to your login screen

And use

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->beforeFilter(function(){
        if (!Auth::check())
            return Redirect::to('admin/login')->with('message', 'You need to be logged in!');
    });
}
```

In your controller to restrict a user not login to login

Comment: This is an API so I'm returning a JSON response:

    $status = array (
            'message' => 'Successfully logged out',
            'type' => 'success'
        );

        return Response::json($status, 200);

Answer (score -2):

In the spirit of solving problems and moving on, here's what works as a band-aid:

```
    //standard logout method
    Auth::logout();

    sleep(1);

    //finally logged out!!!!
    Auth::logout();
```

Comment: how do you think same function would work after sleep ?